# Advice on building a server connected android app

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, server

I'm creating a personal project, an Android application, where user sign ins via a server are essentially.  Also users will be able to share important "updates" in both a data stream that all users can have access to, and potentially down the line a data stream that will be specific to local users.

Unfortunately I have basically no idea of how to implement the server for this application.  I'm confident that I'll be able to create a solution though, I just need to be pointed in the right direction.  Are there any existing servers/api's that I could access that will allow me to handle my "connected" tasks? If I were to make a server myself for this application where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

If you have absolutely no experience with server side coding, you should start with PHP and MySQL to create a simple API for your app. 
For getting started download the XAMPP bundle that has everything you need.

SQL and PHP are fairly easy for beginners. On the client(Android) side use Volley as it is simple to understand.

However if you want to get started with Node.js, your server can be up in a few minutes with express.js